# Debugging a CSS snippet - removing a blue square around a button

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/custom-login-registration-amp-forgot-password

Using this snippet I see the login button has the following CSS properties:

```
.login-form-1 .login-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: -25px;
  top: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #999999;
  padding: 11px 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  border: 5px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}
.login-form-1 .login-button:hover {
  color: #555555;
  transform: rotate(450deg);
}
.login-form-1 .login-button.clicked {
  color: #555555;
}
.login-form-1 .login-button.clicked:hover {
  transform: none;
}
.login-form-1 .login-button.clicked.success {
  color: #2ecc71;
}
.login-form-1 .login-button.clicked.error {
  color: #e74c3c;
}
```

It is a pretty cool snippet, but I have a problem when the login button arrow is actually clicked. A blue square forms around it that does not dissapear until the users clicks elsewhere. I cannot find it in this piece of code what is causing that to happen. I am trying to actually remove pieces of this snippet just so I can have purely the login and password and remember me and have the button when clicked call a function that I can then find the form info later to use.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you just need to add a simple sytle to .login-form-1 .login-button { outline: none; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What solved it was:

```
.className {  
  outline: none;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your ID, class, or tag:

```
.className {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  
  -moz-user-select: none;    
  -ms-user-select: none;     
  user-select: none;  
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/

Comment: I was looking at the wrong form, every time I logged on, the form was obscured by that double paneled overflow layout. I would see the snippet's title and 4 forms none of them was the right one.  That's great that you solved it, it never occurred to me that some properties that are not showing on the devtools could actually be active still. How did you find outline? The computed style reported `0px none white`. Upped btw.